# Using HBql Zookeeper will not attempt to authenticate using SASL

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I wanted to test the HBql for simple usage of HBase.I followed the steps described on HBql Website ( http://www.hbql.com/installation.html ). At the end when typing the version-command in HBql-console to verify my installation, i get the following messages:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.4-1386507, built on 09/17/2012 08:33 GMT
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=aleebi
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_18
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=:/usr/local/hbase-0.94.2/hbase-0.94.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.4/contrib/index/hadoop-index-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/hbql-0.90.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase-transactional-tableindexed/org/apache/hbase-trx-0.90.0RC3.jar:/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/lib/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase-0.94.2/lib:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.4/lib:/usr/local/commons-configuration-1.9/commons-configuration-1.9.jar:/usr/local/commons-configuration-1.9/apache-commons-lang.jar:/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.4/zookeeper-3.4.4.jar:/usr/local/slf4j-1.7.2/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/slf4j-1.7.2/slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar::/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/lib/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1/hbql-0.90.0.1
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-5-amd64
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=aleebi
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/home/aleebi
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/hbql-0.90.0.1
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:348)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
24.10.2012 12:57:55 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper <init>
INFO: The identifier of this process is 4698@aleebi
24.10.2012 12:57:55 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper retryOrThrow
WARNUNG: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
24.10.2012 12:57:55 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RetryCounter sleepUntilNextRetry
```

These messages were only printed when using HBql console. HBase work successfully in distributed mode, storing data in HDFS on Debian squeeze.Do you need more information? What mistakes i did? Why SASL is here needed and in general situation like HBase shell not?

maybe some important config:

*hbase-env.sh*

```
hbase_manage_zk=true
```

*hbase-site.xml*

```
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

I have installed HBase recently with Nutch and Solr and had a similar problem. I am not sure if exactly the same and unfortunately I do not have the logs any more but it was definitely connection related.

It turned out that the default connection limit for ZooKeeper was too low and increasing this value in `hbase-site.xml` solved it for me:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
    <value>1000</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This answer assumes you work on linux and edited your etc/hosts file accordingly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540883/1607022)

The client port number for zookeeper must be same in configuration files of HBase and whatever you use on top of it.
Solution is; (in my case HBASE 0.90.4 with GORA 0.3) check your hbase-default.xml under your HBASE_HOME/src/main/resources:

```
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
```

And there should be a hbase-site.xml under HBql:

```
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
<description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
The port at which the clients will connect.
</description>
</property>
```

Port numbers should be the same.